# Question about Storing Laravel File Uploads on File System vs. Database, and how to Store in DB instead of File System if desired

Tags: laravel, file-upload, blob, storage

Just starting to work with File uploads in Laravel 8.x.  I have a UI built and routes and a Controller, and I'm having an internal debate about where and how to store the files.  The expectation is that the files will be .gif, .jpg, .png, .pdf, ?.docx, and possibly some video files types, but mostly .pdf, and we might restrict to .pdf only to make it easier initially.  Also, the file size probably won't be more than 1-2 MB per file and would probably cap that at 10 MB max.  There are up and downsides to using the file system vs. a database for that.  I would want a DB anyways, so the question is whether to just store the path to the file system in the database, or to store the mime_type and some other info in the DB, along with a BLOB or base64 encoded version of the file, probably the base64 version.

I like the idea of using a BLOB or base64 because then it is all self-contained in the DB.  The queries would be the same either way really because you would either have the raw data or a path to the file data in the DB.  You take a hit on size using base64, but for smaller file sizes, not huge, and those are easier to deal because I will want to use data urls to display the file on the front end, or otherwise convert the blob to a dataurl with js.  So, not really sure what the difference is for BLOB vs. base64 in the DB.

That is all just background, but welcome feedback.

The issue that I am having in the controller is probably simple because I have never worked with the Laravel File Methods.  All I have so far is this, although I would probably want to extend that to an array of files rather than just one.

```
protected function attachToRequest(Request $request) {

    Log::info($request->input('parent'));
    Log::info($request->file('file'));
    Log::info($request->file('file')->getClientOriginalName());
    Log::info($request->file('file')->getMimeType());
    Log::info($request->file('file')->getRealPath());
    Log::info($request->file('file')->getSize());
    Log::info(var_dump($request->file('file')->get()));       
    
}
```

because I just want to understand how the Laravel File Facade works, so this is helpful:

https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Support/Facades/File.html

As a test case, I am seeing something like this is the laravel.log file when I post a file to the web routes:

```
2021-08-07 16:17:16] local.INFO: 2  
[2021-08-07 16:17:16] local.INFO: /tmp/php3pLWBc  
[2021-08-07 16:17:16] local.INFO: x.pdf  
[2021-08-07 16:17:16] local.INFO: application/pdf  
[2021-08-07 16:17:16] local.INFO: /tmp/php3pLWBc  
[2021-08-07 16:17:16] local.INFO: 27856  
[2021-08-07 16:17:16] local.INFO:
```

The part that I am stuck on is how to get the raw data for the file with something like file_get_contents or the Facade method, so that I can convert it to base64 or just the BLOB and store it in a database table if I want to play around with that.

I have Laravel running on NGINX and PHP in a docker container, and when I examine the /tmp directory using docker exec, I just seem some log files and a bunch of session ids, and I think my php info list the /tmp upload as empty.

Seems like there should be a really easy way to store it in the database rather the file system if I want to.

I'd like to try the DB method first and then delete the upload from wherever it is in a /tmp folder and also from the file storage for Laravel.  If I'm not happy with that I can use the file system.

**config/filesystems.php**

```
'disks' => [

    'local' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app'),
    ],

    'public' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
        'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],

    's3' => [
        'driver' => 's3',
        'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
        'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
        'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'),
        'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
        'url' => env('AWS_URL'),
        'endpoint' => env('AWS_ENDPOINT'),
    ],
    'patients' => [
    
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('patients'),
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ]

],

'links' => [
    public_path('storage') => storage_path('app/public'),
],
```

If I were to use the file system I would probably want to create another storage path for these files, something like:

```
    'request_attachements' => [
    
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('request_attachements'),
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ]
```

Comment: Store file upload to database ? I prefer store file in side storage folder and save just path where file saved

Comment: That doesn't really help.  There are upsides and downsides to that.  I would like to know how to do either one so I can set it up and test it, so I have the option either way.  Editing the question to add my sample filesystems config.  If you tell me how to get the path on the file system and the raw data, I can continue coding it to test.

Comment: Answer is simple - do not store files in database in all cases.

Comment: Edited the question to add that.  In the database, I would have columns for both the path and for a BLOB or base64 to accommodate either option.

Comment: I'll read the documentation if you just care to comment and not provide an answer:  https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem, https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Support/Facades/File.html.

Comment: @EncangCutbray  I updated the question with an answer that "works" for me.  Have a storage folder and option to store in a DB, as well.

Comment: @Maksim  Your comment really wasn't that helpful.  I am aware of the pros and cons of using file storage vs. DB storage, although would like to explore that for my application.  After digging into the documentation and writing some code, I can do both now, and even do some comparisons between both methods since I've implemented both for development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to answer the first part of my question, probably obvious for someone who is familiar with uploading files using Laravel.

That seems to work because I have that "disk" created and the file that I uploaded in that directory with a uuid and the file extension appended.  I could then just use what is below.  The $contents is what I can base64encoode, or not, and then store as a BLOB in the database, and I also have url to the storage disk.  That is what I was looking for because not I can finish writing the code.  sample url generated looks like:

```
2/aOkWzxR7W4yH1vaCW2fbft9yY5dO0GVpJs2jHWnM.png
```

**config/filesystems.php**

```
'requestattachements' => [
        
    'driver' => 'local',
    'root' => storage_path('./requestattachements'),
    'visibility' => 'public',
]
```

**app/Http/Controllers/MyControllers/OrdersController.php**

```
protected function attachToRequest(Request $request) {

    Log::info($request->input('parent'));
    Log::info($request->file('file'));
    Log::info($request->file('file')->getClientOriginalName());
    Log::info($request->file('file')->getMimeType());
    Log::info($request->file('file')->getRealPath());
    Log::info($request->file('file')->getSize());
    
    Storage::makeDirectory('requestattachements');
    $path = $request->file('file')->store(
        $request->input('parent'), 'requestattachements'
    );
    Log::info($path);
    
    $contents = Storage::disk('requestattachements')->get($path);
    Log::info($contents);
    
 }
```

Optionally insert into DB:
DB::connection('mysql2')->table('request_attachments')->insert([** Insert stuff here . . ]);

**routes/web.php**

```
Route::middleware(['auth:sanctum', 'verified'])->post('Orders/attach_request', [OrdersController::class, 'attachToRequest']);
```

One question I do have about that though is whether or not the files in that storage container are accessible via the web ?

My storage folder structure is like below, and there is a symlink created with php artisan storage:link, which is basically:

ln -s storage/app/public public/storage

```
drwxrwxrwx@  app
drwxrwxrwx@  debugbar
drwxrwxrwx@  framework
drwxrwxrwx@  logs
drwxr-xr-x   orderattachments
drwxr-xr-x@  requestattachements
```

I take it that the files in requestattachments, etc. are not accessible unless I use a helper function to get those, and I should change the permission as needed ?